# How to use speech bubble from qTip2

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, qtip2

Is there someone here who know how to use qTip², a jquery plugin. I want to use the "speech bubble tip" but I don't know how to do it.

I added the links :

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/jquery.qtip.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.qtip.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/jquery.qtip.js"></script>
```

And I'm trying to display a speech bubble on a button.
Here is my button :

```
<button  type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="submit_button_traitement">Submit</button>
```

And here is my js code :

```
<script>
$(function(){
$('#submit_button_traitement').qtip({
    content: {
        text: 'Tips plugin element'
    },
    events: {
        render: function(event, api) {
            // Grab the tip element
            var elem = api.elements.tip;
        }
    }
})
)};
</script>
```

Help please !

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't figure out the "speech bubble tips" plugin he has on his website (I don't think the qTip2 documentation good at all) but the reason your code is not working  is because  you wrapped it in `$(function)`. Once I removed that, it worked. Also make sure your `<script>` section is after your `<html>`.

If you wanted it to look like a speech bubble, you could maybe use a custom CSS class applied to the tooltip to give it that look. I gave an example in the fiddle below:

http://jsfiddle.net/cx4n0p0u/1/

Comment: Thanks, I've already solved this problem but your advice about the styling will help me a lot !! :)